# How to override or pipe a nested builder with built_value?

Tags: flutter, dart, built-value

I have an API which sends me a type :

```
type Response = {
  id: string;
  values: Stringified<number[]>, // string
}
```

where `type Stringified<T> = string;` and is what you would get by using `jsonEncode`.

I want to create a `Built` class that matches the response architecture. This is what I have for now:

```dart
@SerializersFor([
  MyResponse,
])
final Serializers _serializers = (_$_serializers.toBuilder()
      ..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())
    .build();

abstract class MyResponse implements Built<MyResponse, MyResponseBuilder> {
  factory MyResponse([void Function(MyResponseBuilder) updates]) = _$MyResponse;

  MyResponse._();

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return _serializers.serializeWith(MyResponse.serializer, this)! as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }

  static MyResponse fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _serializers.deserializeWith(MyResponse.serializer, json)!;
  }

  static Serializer<MyResponse> get serializer => _$myResponseSerializer;

  String get id;

  List<int> get values;
}
```

This would work if I was receiving/sending data like :

```json
{ "id": "id", "values": [0, 1, 2] }
```

But the data I receive or need to send is:

```json
{ "id": "id", "values": "[0, 1, 2]" }
```

How can I override the `toJson` / `fromJson` of `values` or how can I add a pipe/how so I can use `jsonEncode`/`jsonDecode` when exporting to/importing from a JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to do it with a [`SerializerPlugin`](https://pub.dev/documentation/built_value/latest/serializer/SerializerPlugin-class.html) :

Here is a more complete example with 2 models:

```
type Model1 {
  boolean: boolean;
  integer: number;
}

type Model2 = {
  char: string;
  list: Stringified<Model1[]>;
}
```

where type `Stringified<T> = string;` and is what you would get by using `jsonEncode`.

I created those built value classes:

```dart
// model_1.dart

import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/standard_json_plugin.dart';

part 'model_1.g.dart';

@SerializersFor([
  Model1,
])
final Serializers _serializers =
    (_$_serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();

abstract class Model1 implements Built<Model1, Model1Builder> {
  Model1._();
  factory Model1([void Function(Model1Builder) updates]) = _$Model1;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return _serializers.serializeWith(Model1.serializer, this)
        as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }

  static Model1 fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _serializers.deserializeWith(Model1.serializer, json)!;
  }

  static Serializer<Model1> get serializer => _$model1Serializer;

  bool get boolean;

  int get integer;
}
```

```dart
// model_2.dart

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/standard_json_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_stable/model_1.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_stable/my_plugin.dart';

part 'model_2.g.dart';

@SerializersFor([
  Model2,
  Model1,
])
final Serializers _serializers = (_$_serializers.toBuilder()
      ..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())
      ..addPlugin(MyPlugin()) // <- Add the plugin here.
      ..addBuilderFactory(
        const FullType(BuiltList, [FullType(Model1)]),
        ListBuilder<Model1>.new,
      ))
    .build();

abstract class Model2 implements Built<Model2, Model2Builder> {
  Model2._();
  factory Model2([void Function(Model2Builder) updates]) = _$Model2;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return _serializers.serializeWith(Model2.serializer, this)
        as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }

  static Model2 fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _serializers.deserializeWith(Model2.serializer, json)!;
  }

  static Serializer<Model2> get serializer => _$model2Serializer;

  String get char;

  BuiltList<Model1> get list;
}
```

```dart
// my_plugin.dart

class MyPlugin extends SerializerPlugin {
  @override
  Object? afterDeserialize(Object? object, FullType specifiedType) {
    return object;
  }

  @override
  Object? afterSerialize(Object? object, FullType specifiedType) {
    if (specifiedType.root == BuiltList &&
        specifiedType.parameters.length == 1 &&
        specifiedType.parameters.first.root == Model1) {
      return jsonEncode(object);
    } else {
      return object;
    }
  }

  @override
  Object? beforeDeserialize(Object? object, FullType specifiedType) {
    if (specifiedType.root == BuiltList &&
        specifiedType.parameters.length == 1 &&
        specifiedType.parameters.first.root == Model1) {
      return jsonDecode(object as String);
    } else {
      return object;
    }
  }

  @override
  Object? beforeSerialize(Object? object, FullType specifiedType) {
    return object;
  }
}
```

Notice the `class MyPlugin extends SerializerPlugin` in `model_2.dart`. I add this plugin to the `Model2` serializer.

It

- Overrides `afterSerialize` that applies `jsonEncode` to the serialized list of serialized model1
- Overrides `beforeDeserialize` that applies `jsonDecode` to the deserialized stringified list of serialized model1

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this fit to your need. I ussually modify my `toJson()` method by changet its value.

for example: in my model I use `@JsonSerializable` which will generated default `toJson`.to customize some keys, i do like below:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = _$MyModelToJson(this);
    data['status'] = status?.id;
    return data;
  }
```

---

maybe you can use similar pattern.

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
   final  data = _serializers.serializeWith(MyResponse.serializer, this)! as Map<String, dynamic>;

   data['values'] = "${data['values']}";

   return data;
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid modifying the json by hand and would like to only use features of built value. The reason is that it is error-prone and not type safe